# Ruby array starting at 1

Tags: ruby

I have an array with indices 0..n  The 0th position is nil.  My information starts at position 1.  What is a Ruby way of traversing this array and start with position one.  Currently what I'm doing is the following:

```
(1...@vertices.length).each do |index|
  do something with @vertices[index]
end
```

Comment: why not use 0-based arrays like everyone else?

Comment: `@vertices[1..-1].each do |elem|`, but it's crazy.

Comment: I'm building chemical formula names.  And to avoid confusion, I want to store a molecule with 1 Carbon atom in @vertices[1].

Comment: @mikeglaz: That looks like a bad data-structure to store molecule information. Why not a hash? `{"h" => 2, "s" => 1, "o" => 4}`. A hash is even ordered in >= 1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm building chemical formula names. And to avoid confusion, I want to store a molecule with 1 Carbon atom in @vertices[1]

Use a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html) instead:

```
@vertices = {
  1 => 'Molecule with 1 carbon atom',
  2 => 'Molecule with 2 carbon atoms',
  5 => 'Molecule with 5 carbon atoms'
}

@vertices.each do |carbon_atoms, molecule|
  # do something with molecule
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure why you're starting from index 1, as 0 is standard, but the way I would approach this is either:

```
@vertices[1..-1].each { |element| do_what_you_planned_on_doing }
```

or

```
@vertices.each_with_index do |ele, index|
  next if index == 0
  do_what_you_planned_on_doing
end
```

I prefer the first one. It seems more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.upto(array.size) {|index| array[index] }
```

This will use the `upto` method to manage an index, and then you use the index to access the element of the array.

Not sure why it matters that nil is in the 0 position, I don't think it pertains to how to traverse from index 1 in an array.  In fact, there is no need to mention that you have an array with indices from 0 to n as that describes very array in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to throw away the first one if you don't want it.

```
@vertices.shift
@vertices[0]
# => the one you want
```

`shift` is to remove the first element and return it. It changes the array itself. Doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift